# Accounting every minute data

Tags: r, time-series

I get real time data by the minute, and sometimes they miss the minute data.
A day has 1440 minutes, and I need to figure out a way to have data for all the 1440 minutes. If there is timestamp missing I need to fill it in with the average of the daily data. Can you help me figure this out using R, (tidyverse preferred).
The current time stamps are as follows:
07-06-2022 15:20:10 (they have seconds)

To be precise I have data that looks like the following:

```
time                 quantity 
07-06-2022 15:43:01    1
07-06-2022 15:44:17    2
07-06-2022 15:45:10    6
07-06-2022 15:45:54    7
07-06-2022 15:48:29    10
```

in the above data set one can see that there are two entries for 07-06-2022 15:45. and there missing minutes of data (15:46 and 15:47). I need to write a code that accounts for the missing time stamps and their respective data set. The missing timestamps data (quantity) can have average of the data set per day.
Basically I should account for all the 1440 minutes in a day and get a total table per day.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have clarified above please let me know if that helps

Comment: We need you to tell us what "account for" means.  That is, how exactly do you plan to use these *imputed values*?

Comment: I need to create daily totals, and since there are missing time stamps with its respective data the daily total is off by a huge error. So i was hoping to reduce the error percentage by filling the missing time stamp data with average of the data for that particular day. does that help?

Comment: Yes.  That information is so important, in fact, that you should include it explicitly in your post.  One other important piece of information concerns the *pattern* or *reason* for missingness.  Why are entries missing? Does this occur due to some random process or does it occur, say, when quantities have certain values or at certain times of day?  What does the spacing of the time stamps mean?  These answers are *hugely* important if you want to get responses that will lead to accurate estimates.

Comment: Do you have a way to evaluate alternative methods for filling in the missing quantities? What do you mean by "the daily total is off by a huge error"?

Comment: @whuber the missing time stamps could be due to processing error. its real time data so i get data of every minute.  and the total of every day helps with calculations of daily usage. if there are missing time stamps then i wont have the daily total accurate enough and will be off by a huge margin. a small percentage error is fine, but missing time stamps would have a huge error in the actual total and calculated error. I am new to R so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's a much easier way to create daily totals: sum up the entries you do have, and then multiply by 1440/n, where n is the number of entries you have.

This -- like the method you suggest -- depends on one big assumption: that the missing numbers are, in some sense, "the same" as those you get. This might not at all be the case. Imagine, for example, that the reason you're missing data is that the system is overloaded and the numbers you get are some sort of measure of system load.

---

Assuming the numbers you've shown us here are a truly random sample and there's no time dependence, a rough estimation of the daily total would be $\frac{1440}{5} \cdot 26 = 7488$, since you showed us five entries and they sum to 26.

Comment: can you show an example with the data i have given? how would i know the n value for different days? can we add a loop that checks that for everyday i am new at R so the example would help.

Comment: @user363186 , it's literally just 1440/count * sum -- I edited my answer with an example. If you need help with summing and counting things in R I suggest you ask those questions separately.

Comment: i tried that but the total is off, is there anyway we can fill the previous time values for the missing time.?\

Comment: That would be just as off in that case, so I don't see why bother. It would be easier to help you if you would open a new question with more details than just saying it's "off" because that could mean you're doing one in literally a million things wrong.